# Can I create an Anki deck from a .CSV file?

Tags: csv, export, anki

Can I convert my CSV file into an Anki deck? I can't find any options in the program.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The desktop [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/#download) version will allow you to import "**Text separated by tabs or semicolons**." Use this option to choose your CSV file. After opening the file, you will be presented with a dialog which allows you to customize how your data is imported.  One of the settings is an option that lets you choose the delimiter.  Change this to a comma, and it should work for you.

[image: Screenshot: Importing a CSV file into Anki]

Comment: Also you have to set up an encoding for UTF-8

Comment: Can it be used to insert new cards into existing deck?

Comment: How did you do that? I have a deck  with "Note ID". Yet, it doesn't appear in the mapping choices: just Front, Back or Ignore.

Answer (score 20):

Another way to generate `.apkg` files is by programmatically reusing the desktop version with Python. Extend:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/share/anki: python ...
```

Then you can adapt the following example to your needs:

```
import anki
from anki.exporting import AnkiPackageExporter

collection = anki.Collection(os.path.join(TMPDIR, 'collection.anki2'))

deck_id = collection.decks.id(FBASENAME + "_deck")
deck = collection.decks.get(deck_id)

model = collection.models.new(FBASENAME + "_model")
model['tags'].append(FBASENAME + "_tag")
model['did'] = deck_id
model['css'] = """
.card {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.from {
  font-style: italic;
}
"""

collection.models.addField(model, collection.models.newField('en'))
collection.models.addField(model, collection.models.newField('ru'))

tmpl = collection.models.newTemplate('en -> ru')
tmpl['qfmt'] = '<div class="from">{{en}}</div>'
tmpl['afmt'] = '{{FrontSide}}\n\n<hr id=answer>\n\n{{ru}}'
collection.models.addTemplate(model, tmpl)
tmpl = collection.models.newTemplate('ru -> en')
tmpl['qfmt'] = '{{ru}}'
tmpl['afmt'] = '{{FrontSide}}\n\n<hr id=answer>\n\n<div class="from">{{en}}</div>'
collection.models.addTemplate(model, tmpl)

model['id'] = 12345678  # essential for upgrade detection
collection.models.update(model)
collection.models.setCurrent(model)
collection.models.save(model)

note = anki.notes.Note(collection, model)
note['en'] = "hello"
note['ru'] = u"[heləʊ]\nint. привет"
note.guid = "xxx1"
collection.addNote(note)

note = collection.newNote()
note['en'] = "bye"
note['ru'] = u"[baɪ]\nint. пока"
note.guid = "xxx2"
collection.addNote(note)

export = AnkiPackageExporter(collection)
export.exportInto(FONAME)
```

As long you keep `note.guid` and `model['id']` the same, you can import the DB and **update** cards **without losing progress**!

- [Any way to build apkg from command line without GUI?](https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions/ankidesktop/19429-any-way-to-build-apkg-from-command-line-without-gui)
- [Is it possible to merge improvements and corrections to cards during apkg import without loosing progress?](https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions/ankidesktop/19461-is-it-possible-to-merge-improvements-and-corrections-to-cards-during-apkg-import-without-loosing-progress)

examples of my production code:

- http://hg.defun.work/gadict/file/tip/py/gadict_srs_anki.py or [copy](http://hg.defun.work/gadict/file/53fd793e345d/py/gadict_srs_anki.py)
- http://hg.defun.work/gadict/file/tip/obsolete/exp_anki.py or [copy](http://hg.defun.work/gadict/file/53fd793e345d/obsolete/exp_anki.py)

Comment: Thanks - this example is really helpful.
But what does `FBASENAME` refer to?

Comment: *You have to provide some unique names, later you'll see them in card browser*. Choose whatever you want, for consistency I externalized it at the prefix, plz follow links to actual code in the repository for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

### Anki API

To build on [gavenkoa's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1127023/93066), the Anki API has built-in functionality to import from CSV.

First of all, you can install the anki Python package using pip, e.g.

```
pip3 install anki protobuf
```

Here's a very basic example to import from CSV and export a deck to an Anki package (.apkg) file:

```python
import anki
from anki.exporting import AnkiPackageExporter
from anki.importing.csvfile import TextImporter

# Create a new collection
collection = anki.Collection('/path/to/test.anki2'))

# Create a new deck in the collection (otherwise the "Default") deck will be used
deck_id = collection.decks.id('Deck name')
model = collection.models.byName('Basic')
model['did'] = deck_id
collection.models.save(model)

# Import cards from CSV into the new collection
importer = TextImporter('/path/to/test.csv'))
importer.initMapping()
importer.run()

# Save and export the collection to an Anki package (.apkg) file
collection.save()
exporter = AnkiPackageExporter(collection)
exporter.exportInto('/path/to/test.apkg'))
```

A more detailed example is here: https://github.com/bmaupin/flashcard-sets/blob/main/scripts/csv-to-apkg.py

The official Anki python API is documented here: https://addon-docs.ankiweb.net/getting-started.html

The official documentation isn't comprehensive, but I've also documented it a little bit myself: https://github.com/bmaupin/flashcard-sets/tree/main/scripts#anki-api

When using the API, it's also helpful to be familiar with some of the basic concepts: https://docs.ankiweb.net/getting-started.html#key-concepts

### Genanki

Another option is to use this package: https://github.com/kerrickstaley/genanki

It's not officially affiliated with the Anki project but seems to have a cleaner and more well-documented API, in addition to a more liberal licence.